# xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" URI is not registered

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I want to build an android application with `maven`. using [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/) I create a xml file named `pom.xml` with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

but in the 
`xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` 
and 
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"` 
I've got error:

```
URI not registered
```

1. what is this error for? and
2. how can I fix it?

Comment: I faced same error in intelij Idea, I resolved by following https://www.programmersought.com/article/73415408156/

Answer (score -2):

Because your pom.xml isn't a Maven Project xml.
If you use IDE,notice the IDE notify,maybe it tell you what want to do.
Follow the hint,and do it.

Comment: This should be comment